# How to use RecyclerView to implement the HorizontalScrollView?

Tags: android

I want to make a screen with a ***grid of items*** which is able to **scroll horizontally**. Those items are a combination of **Images and text**. It should be possible with `RecyclerView` but I am unable to do it.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem ? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use a [HorizontalGridView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/HorizontalGridView.html)?

Comment: post the code what have you done till now

Comment: [SOLVED ]Solved here, it is quite easy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37619660/1303639

Answer (score 1):

Set GridLayoutManager to recycle view as follows.

```
GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
recyleView.setLayoutManager(manager);
```